# How to extract values from a list of maps based on another list of values

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have a list of map:

```
final list1 = [
        {
            "article": "1",
            "category": "accessory"
        },
        {
            "article": "1",
            "category": "tennis"
        },
        {
            "article": "2",
            "category": "tennis"
        },
        {
            "article": "2",
            "category": "ball"
        },
        {
            "article": "2",
            "category": "accessory"
        },
        {
            "article": "3",
            "category": "tennis"
        },
        {
            "article": "3",
            "category": "clothes"
        },


];
```

As you see, here I have 3 unique articles : `["1", "2", "3"]`, but 4 unique categories: `["accessory", "tennis", "ball", "clothes"]`.

Now I want to extract values from `list1` based on:

```
final categoryList = ["tennis", "accessory"];
```

I need to extract the articles from a "list1" containing all categories in a "categoryList".

My expected result:

```
list2 = ["1", "2"];
```

Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should the result be if multiple articles does have all the categories in your `categoryList`? E.g. if `categoryList` is just `["tennis"]`?

Comment: In this case:
```
list2=[{
            "article": "14314",
            "category": "tennis"
        },
        {
            "article": "14316",
            "category": "tennis"
        }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first invert your data structure so that instead of having a `List` of `Map`s where each `Map` has an article ID and a single category, you have a single `Map` of categories to a `List` of article IDs. (And actually, a `Set` of categories would make matching easier than a `List`.)

Once you have that, then you could iterate over the desired categories from `categoryList`, retrieve the resulting `Set`s of associated article IDs, and use [`Set.interaction`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set-class.html) to find the intersection of all of them:

```dart
void main() {
  // Original `List` of `Map`s.
  final list1 = [
    {"article": "1", "category": "accessory"},
    {"article": "1", "category": "tennis"},
    {"article": "2", "category": "tennis"},
    {"article": "2", "category": "ball"},
    {"article": "2", "category": "accessory"},
    {"article": "3", "category": "tennis"},
    {"article": "3", "category": "clothes"},
  ];

  // Create a single `Map` of categories to article IDs.
  var categories = <String, Set<String>>{};
  for (var map in list1) {
    var category = map['category']!;
    var articles = categories[category] ??= <String>{};
    articles.add(map['article']!);
  }

  final categoryList = ["tennis", "accessory"];

  // Search.
  var matchingArticleIDs = <Set<String>>[
    for (var category in categoryList) categories[category] ?? <String>{},
  ].reduce((resultSoFar, set) => resultSoFar.intersection(set));
  print(matchingArticleIDs); // Prints: {1, 2}
}
```

Alternatively, you could have a `Map` of article IDs to a `Set` of categories and just iterate over all entries to find those that have a superset of your desired `categoryList`:

```dart
  // Create a single `Map` of article IDs to categories.
  var articles = <String, Set<String>>{};
  for (var map in list1) {
    var articleID = map['article']!;
    var categories = articles[articleID] ??= <String>{};
    categories.add(map['category']!);
  }

  // Search.
  var matchingArticleIDs = [
    for (var mapEntry in articles.entries)
      if (mapEntry.value.containsAll(categoryList)) mapEntry.key,
  ];
  print(matchingArticleIDs); // Prints: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  final list1 = [
    {"article": "14314", "category": "sport"},
    {"article": "14314", "category": "tennis"},
    {"article": "14316", "category": "tennis"},
    {"article": "14316", "category": "sport"},
    {"article": "14316", "category": "accessory"},
  ];

  final list2 = ["sport", "tennis", "accessory"];

  int compareLength = list2.length;

  var outputList = [];
  for (final i in list1) {
    var listCompare = list1.where((element) => element["article"] == i["article"]).toList();
    if(listCompare.length == compareLength){
      outputList = listCompare;
    }
  }
  
  print(outputList);
  
  //output 
  //[{article: 14316, category: tennis}, {article: 14316, category: sport}, {article: 14316, category: accessory}]
}
```

Try this...

Comment: Thanks, but if there are many articles satisfying the condition, it is returning just one article